# How to use tty device like chardev device?

Tags: linux-kernel

It is possible to use a tty device like a chardev device in kernel module?
I would like to write a kernel module to control some electronics connected by USB port and registered as /dev/ACM0 in Linux. I like to do it the easiest way. So, I would like to treat a tty device like a chardev device and send something like a letter for example to light a diod. It is possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A tty is character device, and in order to implement char device you need write a kernel module, its a bit tricky for linux beginners.

As you stated

> I like to do it the easiest way

and

> control some electronics connected by USB port

I recommend you to use libusb, its more easier to implement USB drivers with libusb, its cross platform and have lots of documentations.

Comment: Yes, but I must create a kernel module for it.